# Delphi, String to date conversion

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have string with the text `"Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000"`

How can I convert it to date format e.g. `03/08/2011 18:51:33`

var
  myDate : TDateTime;

begin
  myDate := StrToDate('Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000');
  ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(myDate));

end;

ERROR: 'Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000' is not a valid date

Comment: You want to convert from one text format to another?

Comment: I want to convert string to date. String:Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000 -> to date : 03/08/2011 18:51:33

Comment: @user3189644 By "date", do you mean a string in the format you gave, or a `TDateTime`?

Comment: Show some minimal effort/knowledge.

Comment: What do you call by date? as of now you shown just two strings, "Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000" and "03/08/2011 18:51:33" - they both are just strings

Comment: Here is what I have tried. I'm Receiving error message: 'Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000' is not a valid date

var
  myDate : TDateTime;

begin
  myDate := StrToDate('Wed, 03 Aug 2011 18:51:33 +0000');
  ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(myDate));

end;